# Ubuntu 14 find what is consuming disk space

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix, shell, ubuntu-14.04

Have any command to see what is consuming disk space on ubuntu 14?

My Ubuntu  server has left only 70MB of disk space

thank's

Comment: There is ample stuff on Google for this.

Comment: ncdu is great : https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can be answered with a simple Google search

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this article can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space/3964#3964

For instance:

`du /home | sort -rn` (will search all files/directories under /home and sort them by largest to smallest.

`du -h /home | sort -rh` (same but will show it in MB/KB/etc) - Note this requires coreutils 7.5 or newer (`sort --version` to check)

You can replace `/home` with any directory of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

A quick `df -h` can show you the volumes and basic usage.

Then I like to drill down by doing
`du -s * | awk '{ if( $1 > 10000 ) { print; } }'`

That will return a list of the directories over 10 MB in size.  You can keep running the command from there as you drill down.  I'd start in the /var, /home, /root, and /usr directories.